# What's the measure of the $\angle POB$ in the circle below?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

For reference:

> If you have a circle with center $O$ and radius $\sqrt5 + 1$.
> through an outer point $P$, the secant $PBA $and the tangent $PE$ are traced. if $PE = AB = 2$, calculate $\angle POB$.(Answer:$18^\circ$)

My progress:

$\triangle ABO(\text{isosceles}) : AB=2, OA=OB = \sqrt5+1 \implies\\
 \angle POA = 36^o, \angle OAB=\angle ABO = 72^o\\
\triangle POE: 2^2+(\sqrt5+1)^2 = OP^2 \implies OP = \sqrt{10+2\sqrt5}$

Th.Stweart:
$\triangle OAP: \\
OA^2.BP+OP^2.2 = BO^2.(2+BP)+(2+BP).2.BP\\
\therefore BP = \sqrt5-1$

Law of cosines
$\triangle POB: \\
BP^2=BO^2+OP^2-2.BO.OP.cos \angle BOP \implies\\ \boxed{\angle BOP=18^o}$

Is the solution possible without using the law of cosines since it results in an unusual angle?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using power of the point $P$ with respect to circle $O$,

$PB \cdot PA = PE^2 \implies PB \cdot (PB +2) = 4$

That gives $PB = \sqrt5 - 1$ and hence $PA = \sqrt5 + 1$

As $PA = OA = \sqrt5 + 1, ~ \angle AOP = \angle APO = 54^\circ$

$ \therefore \angle BOP = 18^\circ$

Comment: In the second line, why you didn't use $PA\cdot(PA-2)=4$? That removes one line :) anyway $\to(+1)$.

Comment: +1 Excellent...

Comment: @A-B-C that was indeed silly of me!

Comment: @A-B-C by the way, we had a friend here who called her/himself ACB and used to be active in Euclidean geometry related questions.

Comment: @A-B-C ok I did not know of the note. Wish him good luck in everything!